# My email template not center in Office 365 inbox

Tags: html, css, newsletter

I have following code in my email template to center in all inboxes. And Working fine in gmail, yahoo mail, outlook. But in office 365 inbox template not centering. My wrapping td taking tex-align:center automatic and that causes not cente my template.

```
<table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" data-role="page" style="padding-top:0px;padding-right:0px;padding-bottom:0px;padding-left:0px;margin-top:0px;margin-right:auto;margin-bottom:0px;margin-left:auto;table-layout:fixed;border-collapse:collapse;font-family:arial;font-size:10pt;background-color:rgb(133, 145, 154);" width="100%">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td align="center" class="full_width" style="margin-top:0;margin-right:0;margin-bottom:0;margin-left:0;padding-top:0;padding-right:0;padding-bottom:0;padding-left:0;" width="100%">

        </td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: office 365 is webmail of outlook ?

Comment: Not working for Webmail of Office 365. Working fine for Outlook.